# java queue with dynamic priority flag

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, priority-queue

I need to build a queue where the elements will be added and removed in chronological order by default. But if the client sets the priority flag for the queue I need to be able to pull the elements based on the priority order of the elements.

I am thinking of creating a priority queue backed by a map that keeps track of the queue index in priority order and based on priority flag I can pull the items from the map and pop the item from index from the queue.

However with this approach the question will be, weather I create the map by default or only if the flag is set (considering the cost of creating the map on fly being high, I am inclining towards having it by default).

Please let me know if there is a better way of doing this or if there is an existing implementation that exists.

Here is what I currently have:

```
import javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class DynamicPriorityQueue<ComparableQueueElement> implements IQueue<ComparableQueueElement> {

    private static final int CONSTANT_HUNDRED = 100;
    private boolean fetchByCustomPriority = false;
    private final ReentrantLock lock;
    private final PriorityQueue<ComparableQueueElement> queue;
    private final PriorityQueue<ComparableQueueElement> customPriorityQueue;

    public DynamicPriorityQueue() {
        this(null);
    }

    public DynamicPriorityQueue(Comparator<ComparableQueueElement> comparator) {
        this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
        this.queue = new PriorityQueue<>(CONSTANT_HUNDRED);
        if (comparator != null)
            this.customPriorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<ComparableQueueElement>(CONSTANT_HUNDRED, comparator);
        else
            this.customPriorityQueue = null;
    }

    public void setFetchByCustomPriority(boolean fetchByCustomPriority) throws OperationNotSupportedException {
        if (this.customPriorityQueue == null)
            throw new OperationNotSupportedException("Object was created without a custom comparator.");

        this.fetchByCustomPriority = fetchByCustomPriority;
    }

    public void push(ComparableQueueElement t) throws InterruptedException {
        if (this.lock.tryLock(CONSTANT_HUNDRED, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            try {
                this.queue.offer(t);
                if (this.customPriorityQueue != null)
                    this.customPriorityQueue.offer(t);
            } finally {
                this.lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    public ComparableQueueElement peek() {
        return this.fetchByCustomPriority ? this.queue.peek()
                : (this.customPriorityQueue != null ? this.customPriorityQueue.peek() : null);
    }

    public ComparableQueueElement pop() throws InterruptedException {
        ComparableQueueElement returnElement = null;
        if (this.lock.tryLock(CONSTANT_HUNDRED, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            try {
                if (this.fetchByCustomPriority && this.customPriorityQueue != null) {
                    returnElement = this.customPriorityQueue.poll();
                    this.queue.remove(returnElement);
                }
                else {
                    returnElement = this.queue.poll();
                    if (this.customPriorityQueue != null) {
                        this.customPriorityQueue.remove(returnElement);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                this.lock.unlock();
            }
        }
        return returnElement;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you efekctive. however my question was if the design will be optimal or do i go ahead with another data structure/approach?

Comment: If all items in a priority queue have the same priority, queue push/pop should be very efficient, in O(1) time.

Comment: Are you asking for a container from which the consumer can choose whether to remove the next element in priority order or, the next element in FIFO order?

Comment: If your queue of items isn't terribly large, simply reorder the queue based on the client's preference. That is, create a new queue using a different comparison function for ordering. How often does this preference change, and how many items are in your queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted my comments after rereading the question, it may get complicated. You need to turn a fifo (chronological) queue into a priority queue with a flag. Your map would need to be ordered and be able to hold repeated values. Otherwise you would need to search the map to find the highest priority or search the queue. I wouldn't do it.

**EDIT**

What about using a wrapping class:

```
class Pointer<T>{
    T element
}
```

And two queues of Pointers where the queues share the Pointers but they return them differently? The only thing you would need to do is to check that "element" is not null (you set it null when it leaves one of the queues.

The Pointer reference remains in the other queue but you check for null before returning.

**EDIT**

Your code doesn't have a map.

```
public ComparableQueueElement peek() {
        return this.fetchByCustomPriority ? this.queue.peek()
                : (this.customPriorityQueue != null ? this.customPriorityQueue.peek() : null);
    }
```

is not correct. If it is not custom you should peek from this.queue

**EDIT**

Note that by using a wrapping class you save yourself the remove calls in the other queue. The only overhead added is that you need to check for null when fetching

Comment: how would creating a linked list with a map of priority ordered linked list indexes work. Let me try that.

Comment: You will need to consider the reverse. If the flag is switched back. That would mean that you need to keep both queues ready to go.

Comment: I think the map would kill you because when the flag is set you would need to find the right priority every time or have multiple maps (per priority)

Answer (score 0):

For me implementation looks fine if your application have the requirement where the flag is changing very frequently. In such case you have both the queues ready to offer or poll object from queue. Although it makes your add operation heavy but retrieval is fast.

But if these changes are not frequent then you can think of re initializing the custom priority queue from FIFO queue only when flag changes.
And perform all your peek,offer operation only on one queue instead of two.
which will be more efficient if FIFO priority is being used.
and if you do that modify your push operation as below -

```
public void push(ComparableQueueElement t) throws InterruptedException {
    if (this.lock.tryLock(CONSTANT_HUNDRED, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
        try {
            this.queue.offer(t);
            if (this.fetchByCustomPriority) // add to customPriorityQueue only when flag is enabled
                this.customPriorityQueue.offer(t);
        } finally {
            this.lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Priya. I understand the cost associated with add operation. However switching of priority can happen pretty often hence the two upfront queues.